# How to fail github action using the new dotnet code-coverage command

Tags: github-actions, code-coverage

I am trying to create a build script to restore, build, test and code coverage a .net solution and then publish the results to sonarcloud. I have succeeded in most of this, but there is a new dotnet step for collecting code-coverage that has been suggested which can be used as follows:

```
 - name: Install dotnet coverage
   run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage

 - name: Coverage
   run: dotnet-coverage collect dotnet test --no-build -f xml  -o 'coverage.xml'
```

The step runs absolutely fine, collects code coverage as expected, but it took me a while to realise that because of the nested call to the dotnet test command, this step does NOT fail when a test fails. To me I'm expecting that to be the default behaviour. Now, aside from splitting out the test command into a separate step to force this, is there a way of making the above line fail when a test fails. Right now I've been forced to do this:

```
- name: Test
  run:  dotnet test --no-build

- name: Coverage
  run: dotnet-coverage collect dotnet test --no-build -f xml  -o 'coverage.xml'
```

Which basically means running the tests twice which seems inefficient. Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` option for `dotnet test` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) to collect coverage data while test runs. You can also set data collector, result file format, name and directory. For example:

```
dotnet test --collect:"Code Coverage;Format=Xml;CoverageFileName=coverage.xml" --results-directory ./coverage
```

Pay attention that although you can specify result directory another one directory(with Guid as name) will automatically be created inside it. Look at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2378) issue.